# Azure Data Sync Frequency Change

Tags: azure

I have sign up in Azure Free Trail set up 2 Azure Database in 2 Different Region and Sync them using azure Data Sync Portal it's works pretty well, but my question is that how to reduce SYNC FREQUENCY.
because azure gives minimum time is 5 minute for automated Sync. but i want this time around 30 sec to 1 minute because my website is of online selling product ( Shopping ) so that i want fast sync 
So is there anyway to workaround this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

5 mins is the lowest interval you can set it to. likewise, the service is never meant for a near-realtime replication.